# Angular Material Checkbox: add true values in an array

Tags: angular, checkbox, angular-material

I have a problem with Angular Material and checkboxes. I would like to create an array with all checked checkboxes but seems that is harder than I tought.
[image]

**dialog-settings.html**

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title>Settings</h1>
<div mat-dialog-content>
  <section [formGroup]="dynamColumns">
    <ul>
      <mat-checkbox color="primary" formControlName="nome">Name</mat-checkbox>
      <mat-checkbox color="primary" formControlName="surname"
        >Surname</mat-checkbox
      >
      <mat-checkbox color="primary" formControlName="date"
        >Date</mat-checkbox
      >
    </ul>
  </section>
</div>
<p>{{ dynamColumns.value | json }}</p>
<div mat-dialog-actions [align]="'end'">
  <button mat-raised-button color="warn" mat-dialog-close>Close</button>
  <button
    style="margin-left: 8px"
    (click)="onSave()"
    mat-raised-button
    color="primary"
  >
    Save
  </button>
</div>
```

**dialog-settings.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dialog-settings',
  templateUrl: './dialog-settings.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dialog-settings.component.scss'],
})
export class DialogSettingsComponent implements OnInit {
  columns: any;
  dynamColumns = this._formBuilder.group({
    name: false,
    surname: false,
    date: false,
  });

  constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.columns);
  }

  onSave() {
    // if checkbox is checked ---> join columns array
  }
}
```

I have already tried accessing dynamColumns.value but I can't figure out how to filter keys and join into an array if value is true.
This is what I get trying a boolean condition on dynamColumns.value

`This comparison appears to be unintentional because the types 'Partial<{ name: boolean | null; surname: boolean | null; date: boolean | null; }>' and 'boolean' have no overlap.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### What's the problem?

The problem is that `value` on `FormGroup` is an object of all the form controls, so you can't compare it against `boolean`. You have to work with it as object.

It's mentioned in [docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#value)

> For an enabled FormGroup, the values of enabled controls as an object
> with a key-value pair for each member of the group.

#### Solution

To get the fields that are true you could use [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) with [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function. Since you didn't specify the return type you want.
I will use `{key: string, value: boolean}` as a return type.

`Object.entries()` will transform the `FormGroup` value object to array of key-value pairs.

Output of `Object.entries()` will look like this

```
[ ['name', false], ['surname', true], ['date', false] ]
```

You can then reduce it back to array based on the condition.

This is how your `onSave()` function could look like.

```
onSave() {
  const output = Object.entries(this.dynamColumns.value).reduce(
      (acc: {key: string, value: boolean}[], [key, value]) => {
        if (value) {
          acc.push({key, value});
        }
        return acc;
      },
      []
    );
   this._dialogRef.close(output); // <-- In case you want to close the dialog
  }
```